# Why does my filter in the review queue change back to its previous setting?

Tags: bug, review-queues

When I'm reviewing close votes I always filter on a tag, either one proposed in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or my own favorite tag.

Since a couple of weeks I noticed that the filter no longer sticks. And given my number of reviews in that queue, I'm pretty confident I know how the system supposed or used to work. After changing the filter after some undefined time the next result I get is from my previous filter setting.

Here is a screenshot where you see my filter on [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and the review item is a [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) question. C# was my filter before I switched to ReactJS.

[image]

Do notice that it is **not** an audit. I already blamed caching but I have the feeling this is caused by a load-balanced webserver where my session state is not correctly shared or my session isn't sticky enough.

The expected behavior should be that my review filter is applied throughout my review session.

Can this be investigated?

Comment: FWIW in [Allow direct linking to a filtered /review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209777/165773) Shog promises that saved filter preferences saved are "sticky" meaning what you observe is not the intended behavior. "The review queue navigation will preserve the querystring once it exists, but if you navigate back into a queue normally you'll be back to your default or saved preferences."