# Added tags on audits misbehaving when using filter link in close vote review

Tags: bug, review-audits

**How it usually works:**

When reviewing close votes using a filter, audits that don't have any tags for your filter get a tag, so they meet your filter criterium.

**The bug:**

When entering the close vote queue through a link with a custom filter ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=%5Bdocumentation%5D) in my case), audits are tagged with one of the tags in the filter stored in my user profile, and not with the filter I'm currently using.

[Bugged audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/18575161?filter-tags=%5Bdocumentation%5D)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

(The original question is not tagged VBA, nor is the review queue filtered VBA, however, my usual close vote filter includes VBA).

Comment: sound like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326751/why-does-my-filter-in-the-review-queue-change-back-to-its-previous-setting

Comment: This is how I avoid audits to be honest. I work on a small set of filtered tags -- java + duplicate + some other stuff -- and just skip when C or PHP questions come along. Because the problem is that while technically I can edit to remove the tag, I have no idea about the rest of it so I would be skipping anyway.

Comment: Wrong tag added, LOL.

Comment: Just FYI, this issue still persists (in the exact form described above). Here's [it happening to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367101/audit-fails-to-prepend-correct-tag)