# Audit Fails to Prepend Correct Tag

Tags: bug, review-audits

**Please note only the first linked duplicate is actually a dupe. The second one predates any "appending tags" behavior in audits.** (Not sure how duplicate list editing works here on meta, but if a gold badge/mod is able to remove the second item, please do so and rollback this edit.)

I was reviewing CVs today in a queue filtered by [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing). Much to my surprise, a question appeared without the tag on it, though it did have [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api), which is among my normal filter tags.

Here's the proof (and [a link to the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665271/linkedin-companies-api-throws-error-code-500-for-company-without-logo)):

[image]

I suspected an audit, and indeed it was. However, usually it is the *filtered* tag that is prepended, not some random other tag. Despite appearances, this question doesn't actually have the [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) tag.

It's important to note I accessed the [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing) filtered queue through a link which had the filter in the URL. My default filtering tags are [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api), [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing), and [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi), so I assume there is some kind of bug which confused the two lists (maybe having [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing) in both was also a part of this).

Comment: also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362317/added-tags-on-audits-misbehaving-when-using-filter-link-in-close-vote-review